# apex sessions and application items

Tags: oracle-apex

So, I have a custom log-in function for an apex application. I want to define some custom user specific data once a user is logged in. I've been trying to use the application-level items, and setting the values I need for when the user is able to log-in. I've added the application item in the shared components. Here is a snippet:

```
apex_util.set_authentication_result(0);
APEX_UTIL.set_session_state(
    p_name => 'ACCESS_LEVEL', 
    p_value => '5'
);
```

Now, I'm trying to access this variable/value on a page, but when I "run" the app, login and go to the page, the value isn't available in the "View Debug" window. So, am I going about this correctly? Why isn't this working? Is there a better way?

Comment: Where is this piece of code exactly? `ACCESS_LEVEL` is your application item?

Comment: I apologize! ACCESS_LEVEL is my application item and, this code is actually in a function that I've setup in the sql workshop (not in any pages/processes)

Comment: You're confusing me 8) Do you run this code/function somewhere during the authentication process? Or do you run this by hand from the workshop when you logged in? If you do run the code in the auth process somewhere, where and when?

Comment: The function/code is a custom log-in function specified in the Authentication Schemes.

Comment: Ok, next step: when you logged in and are on your first page, you select "Session" from the developer bar (where you can see session state for all page items), and at the top you can change the "View" select list to "Application Items". `ACCESS_LEVEL` is `NULL`?

Comment: Okay. Can you try to put the `set_session_state` code in the post-authentication code, or at least after the code where you have retrieved the final session identifier? (I don't have a custom auth but i might be able to help out!)